# Bootstrap Collapse interfering with responsive table layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I put in an earlier question related to this, but I realized I was barking up the wrong tree, so I'm starting over.  I don't know why this became a problem yesterday, but I've been able to reproduce it at a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dspitzle/22Sr5/4/ .  I have two different instances of a table (code included below), the only difference being that I have the thead and tbody tags assigned `class='requests_targets collapse in'` to enable the Collapse functionality (using the chevron button in the caption).  The one with the collapse classes is all squished, so apparently the responsive table structure is being overriden.

On the Fiddle you'll notice that the table layout briefly corrects itself when you collapse the sections (before they disappear).  What the hell is going on here?  You can see that the only CSS and Javascript I've included are the jquery and bootstrap files, along with one function to toggle the chevrons on the buttons.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id='request_header'>
                    <caption class="h2">Outstanding Requests [1]
                        <button class="btn section-toggle btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".requests_targets"><span class="icon_toggle glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        </button>
                    </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Service</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>LastName, FirstName</td>
                            <td>2/28/2014</td>
                            <td>Books/Toys</td>
                            <td>In Progress</td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" \=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" \=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Child</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id='request_header2'>
                    <caption class="h2">Outstanding Requests [1]
                        <button class="btn section-toggle btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".requests_targets"><span class="icon_toggle glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        </button>
                    </caption>
                    <thead class="requests_targets collapse in">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Service</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="requests_targets collapse in">
                        <tr>
                            <td>LastName, FirstName</td>
                            <td>2/28/2014</td>
                            <td>Books/Toys</td>
                            <td>In Progress</td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" \=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" \=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Child</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:  Weird, I must have wiped the code accidentally before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following to your stylesheet. (after calling bootstrap.css)

```
#request_header .collapse.in,
#request_header2 .collapse.in {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

Comment: This is simpler than my solution and seems to accomplish the same. Nice. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/22Sr5/19

Comment: Excellent!  Many, many thanks.  I still don't understand why this suddenly started failing yesterday, nor why other people haven't run into this, but at least I've got a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is setting your table elements to `display: block` (instead of `display: table`, etc.). You'll probably want to use a callback to reverse that.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#request_header2 tr').css('display', 'table-row');
    $('#request_header2 th, #request_header2 td').css('display', 'table-cell');
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: I have no idea what that would look like, specifically what form a callback would take.

Comment: For what it's worth I just tried adding `thead.in, tbody.in {display: table !important;}` to my CSS file (and to the Fiddle) and that by itself didn't do it.

Comment: Ok, I've wiped my CSS attempt and tried your code on the Fiddle (both in its original form and replacing #myCollapsible with .requests_targets), and it does not seem to make a difference.  It sure looked like it should work based on my understanding of what you did.

Comment: I've also tried augmenting your code to cover the entire set of affected structures:
    $('.requests_targets').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#request_header2 thead').css('display', 'table-header-group');
        $('#request_header2 tbody').css('display', 'table-   row-group');
        $('#request_header2 tr').css('display', 'table-row');
        $('#request_header2 th, #request_header2 td').css('display', 'table-cell');
    })

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work better if you get rid of the `<caption />` element inside the collapsible table and write your `<h2 />` title above the table like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FsW48/).

EDIT: fixed broken link.

EDIT2: fixed example by making the table responsive.

Comment: Hmm.  Semantically mine is more appropriate, but yours has the benefit of working.  I'm going to see if isherwood can help me get his fix going, but if it comes down to it I may resort to it.  I'm mainly wondering a) why this only became a problem yesterday and b) why this relatively straightforward interaction of two components of the library is generating this conflict.